# use user's SSH key in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, cron

I've written a BASH script that's automated using Anacron in user mode.
The script executes `rsync` in SSH mode to synchronize files.
The script should use the user's default (password-encrypted) SSH key to authenticate against the SSH server.

This is working as expected, if I run it from a terminal directly.
The well-known dialog box is popping up, prompting the user to unlock the SSH key.
However, if it's triggered by Anacron it doesn't.

I can confirm that Anacron executes the script in user mode, as `whoami` returns the correct username. But the dialog box is not showing up. Instead

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
```

is printed out. Indeed, the specified path doesn't exist.

My anacrontab looks like this:

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# period  delay  job-identifier  command
1         1      user.backup     /usr/local/bin/backup.sh -p ~/.nb/ssh.config >> /tmp/user.backup.log 2>&1
```

Anacron is triggerd from `~/.profile`.
My guess is that I missed to setup the correct environment for the SSH key unlocking process in the anacrontab.

What do I need to do to make this process working in this place?

**edit** This is a duplicate to https://askubuntu.com/questions/900547/ssh-key-unlock-prompt-from-anacron-task

Comment: There is really no way for a task running through anacron to interact with the user.  Consider using a passwordless key specifically for this purpose, possibly limited on the destination to only receiving rsync connections.

Comment: Hmm so it shouldn't be an issue if I use the `-d` option when triggering Anacron from `~/.profile`?

Comment: Sorry, but this is hard to believe. If I use `/usr/sbin/anacron -s -t ${HOME}/etc/anacrontab -S ${HOME}/var/spool/anacron -fn` via a terminal to run anacron in user mode, everything is working as expected. This doesn't look to be related to anacron forking tasks, at least to me. It's just not working when called from `~/.profile`.

Comment: @larsks Your statement simply is not true, sorry. If I install `ssh-askpass` the user actually is prompted to unlock his key. However, this is not the usual dialog that's well-known to the user and the password has to be unlocked for each `rsync` call again and again. This is not what I want. Do I have to set up some kind of user authentication against the password keyring tool or something like this?

Comment: I suspect you will still find my suggested solution a better one than dealing with passphrases.

Comment: If you can run ssh interactively and get a popup window asking your for your passphrase, then your desktop environment is probably setting some environment variables to make that work. Check the SSH documentation for SSH_ASKPASS and SSH_AUTH_SOCK. To make the same thing work from anacron, you'd have to set the same environment variables to suitable values within the anacron job.